# Making abstract property in Python 3 results in AttributeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract, python-decorators

How do you make an abstract property in python?

```
import abc
class MyClass(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    @property
    def foo(self):
        pass
```

results in the error `AttributeError: attribute '__isabstractmethod__' of 'property' objects is not writable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR:

cowlinator is correct, order counts.

Formally:

According to the [formal documentation for the abstract base class ABC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html)

> When abstractmethod() is applied in combination with other method
> descriptors, it should be applied as the **innermost decorator**, as shown
> in the following usage examples:...

(bold is mine for emphasis: not only is ordering important, but `abstractmethod` must be *innermost*)

Not-too-satisfactory explanation:

Decorators like `@property` and `@abstractmethod` are functions that wrap the functions (methods) they decorate. So two decorators result in nested wrappings, with the one closest to the function definition (the lowest in your editor) being the innermost wrapping function.

In the `@property` decorator, the `__isabstractmethod__` internal attribute is declared as a property itself, with only a getter, no setter - making it readonly. This is from the python code for `property` in `builtins.py`

```
    __isabstractmethod__ = property(lambda self: object(), lambda self, v: None, lambda self: None)  # default
```

The first arg is the getter, the second the setter - None in this case - see the constructor here if you don't believe me:

```
   def __init__(self, fget=None, fset=None, fdel=None, doc=None): # known special case of property.__init__
```

In the `@abstractmethod` wrapping the `__isabstractmethod__` attribute is *set* to `True`. See here:

```
    funcobj.__isabstractmethod__ = True
```

That's from the `abc` module, where `funcobj` is the method being decorated. Now, usually that's your would-be-abstract method, but in this case, it's the *property decorator function wrapping the original method*. And as we saw above, that function made `__isabstractmethod__` readonly.

I say "not-too-satisfactory" because there is no proper justification of this - just obscure documentation that you won't find until you run into the problem. It's really just a limitation of the way decorators work I guess.

For extra background, I tracked this [change here in GitHub](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/bfebb7b54a50f01104f7b6169de77f7fc8feb912) (gotta love open-source!) which includes the update to these [release notes](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#abc), which state - also without a lot of explanation:

> abc.abstractproperty has been deprecated, use property with
> abc.abstractmethod() instead.

For deep-deep source of the exception you got, you can see the C source code for [python descriptors here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/23a6db98f21cba3af69a921f01613bd5f602bf6d/Objects/descrobject.c#L263) and search down for 'is not writable' to see where it throws the exception while trying to generate the setter.

Answer (score 22):

It turns out that order matters when it comes to python decorators.

```
@abc.abstractmethod
@property
```

is not the same as

```
@property
@abc.abstractmethod
```

The correct way to create an abstract property is:

```
import abc
class MyClass(abc.ABC):
    @property
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        pass
```

Comment: Why? Could you please describe the reason?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know. I just know that if `abstractmethod` is not the last decorator, it usually causes an error. Python's function grammar documentation doesn't seem to mention anything useful about this https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#grammar-token-python-grammar-decorator