# Correct way to define properties in an abstract python class

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, abstract-class

I have a project where I want to create an abstract base class to define some shared properties and methods I created a simple abstract class that looks like:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class Person(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    #this doesn't seem to work
    # password: str
    
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def getRoles(self) -> list:
        pass

    #neither does this
    @abstractmethod
    @property
    def password(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    @password.setter
    def password(self, password):
        pass
```

I then have a child class that looks like:

```
from src.Person import Person

class User(Person):

    def __init__(self, username: str = "blank", password: str =""):
        super(User, self).__init__()
        self.roles = ["System User"]
        self.username = username
        self.password = password    


    def getRoles(self):
        return self.roles
```

So far so good. Where things get tricky is that I also want a 'wrapper' function that will extend any Person class at runtime. To do that I created a wrapper function that looks like this:

```
from src.Person import Person

def person_wrapper(person: Person):

    class MyWrapper(person):
        def __init__(self, mask: bool, extra_roles: list):
            super(MyWrapper, self).__init__()
            self.mask = mask
            self.extra_roles = extra_roles

        def getRoles(self) -> list:
            return self.getRoles() + self.extra_roles

        def getPassword(self) -> str:
            if self.mask:
                return self.password.encode("ascii")

    return MyWrapper
```

That wrapper then gets called from my main like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    base_env: Person = get_environment("user")
    env = person_wrapper(base_env)( True, ["abc", "123"])
    print(env.getRoles())
    print(env.getPassword())
```

The problem I'm running into is that properties like 'password' don't seem to be visible in the wrapper function. I tried defining them as a instance variable (password: str ) and as a property using decorators. In both cases the IDE flags password as an unresolved attribute reference. If I try to run the code with the field defined as a property I get the error:

```
AttributeError: attribute '__isabstractmethod__' of 'property' objects is not writable
```

I'm not quite sure where I'm going wrong here. What is the correct way to define abstract variables?

Comment: *"So far so good."* -- Hold on, if I run just that part of the code, I get the same error. That said, this is a lot of code and I've only skimmed it, so there might be a small detail I missed. Please make a [mre], and post the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341).

Answer (score 0):

I found three issues that were causing problems in my code. First, it appears that the order of decorators matters (see: [Making abstract property in Python 3 results in AttributeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72736760/making-abstract-property-in-python-3-results-in-attributeerror) for more details). by changing:

```
@abstractmethod
@property
def password(self):
    pass
```

to

```
@property
@abstractmethod
def password(self):
    pass
```

and then doing the same for the setter, I was able to clear up the AttributeError.

Once that was solved, I also needed to remove the `__init__` method definition from my base class. Abstract classes should not get instantiated so it makes no sense to have an initializer.

The final issue was in the wrapper function.

```
def person_wrapper(person: Person):
```

defines a function that is expecting an **instance** of Person. What I actually want is a Person **Type**. To do this I changed the function to:

```
def person_wrapper(person: Type[Person]):
```

With these changes in place, I can now run my example code and get the expected outcome.